# Why am I processing a comma-separated list incorrectly when using etoolbox and kvoptions?

Tags: expansion, etoolbox, kvoptions, comma-separated-list

I'm trying to pick something out of a list that has been passed from some package options by `kvoptions`, but `docsvlist` doesn't appear to be recognising the commas.

I suspect this may be something to do with the Knuth "mouth and stomach" paradigm, but I'm not enough of a TeXnician to understand why, nor how to do it correctly. Can someone explain what's going on?

Here's my MWE:

testx.sty:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{testx}
\RequirePackage{kvoptions}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\SetupKeyvalOptions{family=test,prefix=test@}
\DeclareStringOption{refnames}
\ProcessKeyvalOptions*
\newcommand{\vtag}{(None)}
\csdef{xferret}{}      % This is what I want to extract
\newcommand{\testtag}[1]{%
    \PackageWarning{testx}{Processing #1}
    \def\do##1{%
        \ifcsdef{x##1}{%
            \renewcommand{\vtag}{##1}%
            \listbreak
        }{%
            \PackageWarning{testx}{##1 not selected}
        }
    }%
    \docsvlist{#1}%
}%
\testtag{\test@refnames}
```

test.tex:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[refnames={rat, ferret, 1.0, mole}]{testx}
\begin{document}
\vtag
\testtag{rat, ferret, 1.0, mole}
\vtag
\end{document}
```

The first `\vtag` (set in the package) produces "(None)"

The second `\vtag` produces "ferret"

in the log, we have this:

(from the package):

```
Package testx Warning: Processing rat, ferret, 1.0, mole on input line 22.
Package testx Warning: rat, ferret, 1.0, mole not selected on input line 22.
```

(from the call in the document body)

```
Package testx Warning: Processing rat, ferret, 1.0, mole on input line 5.
Package testx Warning: rat not selected on input line 5.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a classic expansion issue. What happens is that

```
\testtag{\test@refnames}
```

passes `\test@refnames` exactly as written. In writing to the log, this is fully-expanded by TeX, so you see what you expect. However

```
\docsvlist{#1}%
```

sees `\test@refnames` as `#1`, with no commas. So you need to expand `\test@refnames` correctly. Depending on other uses, either to

```
\expandafter\testtag\expandafter{\test@refnames}
```

at point of use or

```
\expandafter\docsvlist\expandafter{#1}%
```

in the internal macro (but not both!). In either case, what happens here is that TeX will follow the `\expandafter` to convert `\test@refnames` into it's content *before* expanding the processing macro.

Comment: Joseph, thank you very much. \expandafter\docsvlist\expandafter{#1} fixes it nicely.