# TeX macro and command expansion?

Tags: tex-core, expansion

I have implemented couple of macros that should remove commas from numbers. It's nasty dirty stuff, but it works when input is number:

```
\removecommas{12,34,56.7} % => 123456.7
```

But it stop working when the input is given by some command, such as:

```
\newcommand\mynumber{12,34,56.7}
\removecommas\mynumber
```

Why is this happening? How can I force TeX to expand `\mynumber` before commas? I've tried:

```
\expandafter\removecommas\mynumber
```

but that didn't seem to help.

Comment: The cause here is very similar to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26746/why-am-i-processing-a-comma-separated-list-incorrectly-when-using-etoolbox-and-kv

Answer (score 21):

You are nearly there with

```
\expandafter\removecommas\mynumber
```

What is needed is a group:

```
\expandafter\removecommas\expandafter{\mynumber}
```

To understand why, you have to remember that TeX grabs arguments as tokens. Taking the example input, in the first case, you expand `\mynumber` to `12,34,56.7`. TeX then grabs `1` as the argument to `\removecommas`, and unsurprisingly nothing actually happens. On the other hand, with the group in place all of `12,34,56.7` is grabbed by `\removecommas`, and the processing takes place as you want.

(Notice that we need two `\expandafter` primitives. The second one is needed to expand past `{`.)

Answer (score 5):

If you need only up to one level expansion, this works:

```
\def\removecommas{\begingroup\catcode`,=9 \doremove}
\def\doremove#1{\scantokens\expandafter{#1\endinput}\endgroup}
```

Answer (score 4):

The other answers explain the macro expansion. However, if all you want to do is to remove the commas in numbers you could use the [`numprint` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/numprint) with the following setup:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{numprint}

\makeatletter%
\renewcommand*\nprt@dotlist{.}% only . for decimal separator in input
\renewcommand*\nprt@ignorelist{,}% ignore , in input
\npdecimalsign{\ensuremath{.}}% use . as decimal output
\npthousandsep{}%
\makeatother%

\begin{document}
\numprint{12,34,56.7}
\end{document}
```