# Code for capital letter in acronym list clashes with other custom commands

Tags: macros, acronyms

I am writing a large report with many acronyms, some of which include each other. I asked about a way to let them do this in a specific way and got a very nice answer. [Acronyms that include other acronyms](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/247623/acronyms-that-include-other-acronyms/247648#247648)

Now I find that i would like my acronyms to start with a capital letter in the list and I found a way to do this, [Capitalize the first letter in acronym list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57975/capitalize-the-first-letter-in-acronym-list), but when I try to use these together I get two errors
`Argument of \@acx has an extra }` and `Paragraph ended before \@acx was completed`

Here is a minimal example

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[english]{babel} % English language/hyphenation
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}        % Math packages
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}   % Enable pdflatex


\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}
\usepackage{etoolbox}


\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\AC@@acro}{] #3}{] \MakeUppercase #3}{}{}
\patchcmd{\AC@@acro}{] #3}{] \MakeUppercase #3}{}{}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\acx}{\protect\@acx}%
\newcommand{\@acx}[1]{%
  \ifAC@dua
    \acf{#1}%
  \else
    \expandafter\ifx\csname ac@#1\endcsname\AC@used
      \acs{#1}%
    \else
      \acl{#1}%
    \fi
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{acronym}
\acro{q}[$Q$]{\acx{rms}reactive power}
\acro{rms}{root mean square}
\end{acronym}

\section{Text}

The \ac{q} is..... \ac{rms}...

\end{document}
```

EDIT:

I want the result to look like:

[image: Result]

Why is this happening? How can I solve it?

Comment: You're basically trying to do `\MakeUppercase\acx`, which of course fails. It's not really clear what you want `\acx` to do.

Comment: @egreg The result I want is the one in the added picture. The first link explains the function of the `\acx` macro and this works perfectly without the upper case code. Yes I would like to do `\MakeUppercase \acx` why is this not possible? Could it be solve by forcing `\acx` to expand first?

Comment: Why is the command patched twice?

Comment: @cfr I do not know. That was the way it was written in the second link, where I found it.

Comment: @Kajsa Just I wouldn't expect the second patch to have any effect because the pattern is no longer matched.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

[image: premature expansion]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{report}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\AC@@acro}{] #3}{] \expandafter\MakeUppercase#3}{}{}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\acx}{\protect\@acx}%
\newcommand{\@acx}[1]{%
  \ifAC@dua
    \acf{#1}%
  \else
    \expandafter\ifx\csname ac@#1\endcsname\AC@used
      \acs{#1}%
    \else
      \acl{#1}%
    \fi
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{acronym}
\acro{q}[$Q$]{\acx{rms}reactive power}
\acro{rms}{root mean square}
\end{acronym}

\section{Text}

The \ac{q} is..... \ac{rms}...

\end{document}
```

Comment: Almost. As you can see Q is not defined with a capital letter in the list. Is there any other difference than the `\patchcmd{\AC@@acro}{] #3}{] \expandafter\MakeUppercase#3}{}{}` line only being used once in this example and twice in mine?

Comment: Now I see the difference. But how can the capitalization of the Q definition be solved?

Comment: Why does `\expandafter\MakeUppercase\ac{rms}` used in the document cause `! Argument of \WSF@suffixcheck has an extra }.` and `! Paragraph ended before \WSF@suffixcheck was complete.`? Should it not mean that `\ac{rms}` is first expanded to 'root mean square' giving `\MakeUppercase root mean square` which should become 'Root mean square'?

Comment: @Kajsa Well, it will try to expand just the `\ac` bit before `\MakeUppercase`, I think - it won't include the `{rms}` bit.

Comment: Ok. That explains why it does not work. Is there a war to force it to expand the whole `\ac{rms}` command? I tried `\expandafter\MakeUppercase\expandafter{\ac{rms}}` which I found here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26747/tex-macro-and-command-expansion . But that does not work either, just produces a lot of errors.

Comment: @Kajsa I'm not sure: that would just expand `\MakeUppercase` after `\expandafter`. So you'd need e.g. `\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\MakeUppercase...` or something. But I think that expanding `\acx` will conflict with the `\protect`, won't it?

Comment: I am not using `\acx` but `\ac` at present.

Comment: @Kajsa Well, you are using `\acx` as well in the argument to `\acro`.

Comment: No, not in the rms case. At present that is the only `\acro` in the list.